# Truncated Multivariate Normal expected value approximation

Tags: monte-carlo, conditional-expectation, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have $\vec{x} \sim N(\vec{\mu}, \Sigma)$. I would like to calculate
$$E[x_i | \vec{x} \geq 0]$$

There are libraries like tmvtnorm (in R) that calculates this for me. However, it seems to be very slow in high dimensions (I'm working with dimensions of around 1000).
I have also tried some monte carlo methods, but it still seems quite slow. Using Gibbs sampling, the convergence seems quite horrible when covariance is vary significant.

I don't need an exact answer. I would be satisified with something close that I can compute quickly. Are there any algorithms for that?

Comment: The cost of Gibbs sampling is linear with the dimension and speed-up is possible when $\Sigma$ is sparse and induces conditional independence.

Comment: Unfortunately the covariance matrix is dense

Comment: This reference could help, maybe: https://surface.syr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1149&context=ecn